# How do I output a folder that I have created without accessing the previously created folders?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a folder and this folder has about 60 subfolders. How can I access this folder, which I have created to a another Python file? For this Method im using tkinter, because i would like to show these in a GUI.

Now I have created a folders with subfolders. This is what my folder looks like now: `main_folder` -> `testOne`, `testTwo`, `testThree`. `testThree` is the newly created folder and and the others were created before that.

Each single folder has 60 subfolders with numbers from 1 to 60. There is data/content in all 60 subfolders in `testOne` and `testTwo`. Only the newly created folder `testThree` contains 60 subfolders, but there is no data or content in the 60 subfolders.

Now to my current problem. I need the folder `testThree` in my other Python file or rather, I need the folder that I previously created with my `entry`. How do I do that?

It must only output the one folder I created. So here only the folder `testThree` should show and the others are to be ignored. To do this, I tried to access the folders:

```
# second.py
my_folder= [item for item in os.listdir('main_folder') if os.path.isdir(os.path.join('main_folder', item))]
print(my_folder)
```

But unfortunately, it prints all the folder from the main_folder. how can i get just the one folder which I have just created.

Comment: How could the software possibly know that?  Indeed, how could a human being possible know that, by looking at the directory listing?  What makes it different?  If you can come up with a rule, then it can be done.  If there's no rule, then there's no way to accomplish this.

Comment: Do you want the NEWEST folder?  That can certainly be done.

Comment: Yes i just want the newset folder, which ive created. I didn't know how to print my question explicitly, but this is the short question from you. How do I get the new folder I created out?

Comment: `sub_folder= np.array([entry.get()])` Why is the numpy library here?

Comment: Otherwise it gives me every single letter from the folder. I have also tried your MEthode, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Instead it calls the complete gui from my python file. That's why I'm trying to access the one folder, which has no content. Is this possible at all?

Comment: @Mayama What is "your method"? The `os.listdir` function returns the names of files and folders in the specified directory. If you save the value entered in the entry (sub_folder) somewhere, you can find the desired subfolder in the `for` loop by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, given a directory `dirx`, here's how you find the most recent directory in `dirx`.  I list all the entries of the directory that are themselves directories.  I construct a list of each directory with its creation time, but with the creation time first.  That way, I can sort that list, grab the last element, and print the name.

```
import os
dirs = [(os.stat(dirx+'/'+d).st_ctime,d) for d in os.listdir(dirx) if os.path.isdir(dirx+'/'+d)]
dirs.sort()
print( dirs[-1][1] )
```

Comment: thx. ive tried your solution and its working.